# EMV Online PIN Verification for POS TerminalS

Tags: payment-processing, emv, pos, cybersource

I want to understand how and where i can perform an EMV Transaction online PIN Verification.
Suppose i have a few POS terminal and also a Visa Cybersource account, i'am able to perform an EMV Transaction  on the terminal , however most EMV Transaction request that we perform an Online PIN verification ,i'm able to extract the basic details needed to charge the card example data ,`trackData` ,`PINBLOCK` ,`KSN` and some `TLV Data`.

I cant find resources to perform an Online PIN Verification if the EMV Transaction request for it ,especially the VISA cybersource developer page, infact i dont know where to perform the verification or how it works.

A brief lessons and directed resources will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a possibility that such content will conflict with contracts such as NDA? It's a good idea to present some documents available online, or at least books and materials that are generally available for purchase, so that you can ask what description of them you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to understand to verify PIN, and in most cases this is very much the standard, but can't help unless you share more details.

- PIN Block is formed from Card number and PIN, and mostly by [ANSI PIN
  Block format 0](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=algorithms-pin-block-formats)
- The received PIN block is Triple DES encrypted by
  the sender's key called AWK ( acquirer working key )
- You need to have the corresponding key IWK ( issuer working key ).
- Send card number, PIN Block, IWK, PIN Block format, PIN Verification Key, PIN
  verification Key index to HSM
- HSM will respond with whether PIN is
  successful or no.